# Using print() inside recursive functions in Python3

Tags: python, recursion, python-3.x

I am following the book Introduction to Computing Using Python, by Ljubomir Perkovic, and I am having trouble with one of the examples in recursion section of the book. The code is as follows:

```
def pattern(n):
    'prints the nth pattern'
    if n == 0:    # base case
        print(0, end=' ')
    else:    #recursive step: n > 0
        pattern(n-1)         # print n-1st pattern
        print(n, end=' ')    # print n
        pattern(n-1)         # print n-1st pattern
```

For, say, `pattern(1)`, the output should be `0 1 0`, and it should be displayed horizontally. When calling the function `pattern(1)`, nothing prints out, however. But if this is followed by a print statement without arguments, then the results are displayed.

```
>>>pattern(1)
>>>print()
0 1 0
```

If I remove the `end` argument of the `print()` functions inside the recursive function, I get correct output (albeit it displays it vertically):

```
>>> pattern(1)
0
1
0
```

This makes me think that the recursive code itself is correct (plus I confirmed it was with the source provided by the book's website, and with the errata sheet). I am not sure, however, why the `print` statement isn't printing the output as the functions run, if the `end` parameter is included. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This problem may be IDE-specific. It does not seem to occur using Python3 run on Ubuntu/gnome-terminal (or in IPython+emacs).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `print` function doesn't always flush the output. You should flush it explicitly:

```
import sys

def pattern(n):
    'prints the nth pattern'
    if n == 0:    # base case
        print(0, end=' ')
    else:    #recursive step: n > 0
        pattern(n-1)         # print n-1st pattern
        print(n, end=' ')    # print n
        pattern(n-1)         # print n-1st pattern
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Note that on python3.3 `print` has a new keyword argument `flush` that you can use to forcibly flush the output(and thus avoid using `sys.stdout.flush`).

---

On a general note I'd decouple the output from the pattern, doing, for example:

```
def gen_pattern(n):
    if n == 0:
        yield 0
    else:
        for elem in gen_pattern(n-1):
            yield elem
        yield n
        for elem in gen_pattern(n-1):
            yield elem

def print_pattern(n):
    for elem in gen_pattern(n):
        print(elem, end=' ')
     sys.stdout.flush()
```

This makes the code more flexible and reusable, and has the advantage of calling `flush` only once, or you could also call it once every `x` elements(actually I believe `print` already does this. It flushes if trying to write many characters on the screen).

In python3.3 the code could be simplified a little:

```
def gen_pattern(n):
    if n == 0:
        yield 0
    else:
        yield from gen_pattern(n-1)
        yield n
        yield from gen_pattern(n-1)
```

Comment: But not flushing in the interactive shell seems _very_ strange.

Comment: @LevLevitsky Not if you do something like `pattern(1); time.sleep(10)`

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that when `end` is used with some value other than a `"\n"` then the print function accumulates the whole value and prints the output only when a newline is to be printed or the loop is over.

See the difference in these two programs:

```
In [17]: for x in range(5):
    print(x,end=" ")
    if x==3:
       print(end="\n")
    sleep(2)
   ....:     
0 1 2 3  #first this is printed
4        #and then after a while this line is printed
In [18]: for x in range(5):
    print(x,end=" ")
    if x==3:
       print(end="\t")
    sleep(2)
   ....:     
0 1 2 3     4   #whole line is printed at once
```